# user not recognized

Tags: support, linked-accounts

hi
sorry for stupid question
i have server account in stackexchange.com platform (stackoverflow, math, stats, gamedev) with nkint:
https://stackoverflow.com/users/433685/nkint

usually my account was recognized and connected but in serverfault no way.. what could be? has i made some errors?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the same OpenID for all of them, go here:
https://serverfault.com/users/67426/user67426?tab=accounts
And it should be an option to link them.

If you did not use the same OpenID then you will have to pick one OpenID and add it to all of your accounts, then see above.

Answer (score 1):

In this particular case, the accounts do not have OpenIDs in common, so there is no way for us to link them. As Chris pointed out, you need to use the same provider across sites for that to happen.